# HTML5 How to specify the canvas belong to item?

Tags: html5-canvas

Is it possible to specify which element belong to this canvas item?

```
    var ctx1 = $("canvas.jqplot-xaxis-tick")[0].getContext('2d');

    ctx1.fillText("Mycontent", 35, 7);
```

I got an issue when display two items canvas, the content of item2 always override by this code above. I want to do like that :

```
    var ctx1 = [item1]$("canvas.jqplot-xaxis-tick")[0].getContext('2d');
```

Comment: Try by  var ctx1 = $("canvas.jqplot-xaxis-tick:first").getContext('2d'); if your html stucture is 
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="jqplot-xaxis-tick"></div>
  <div class="jqplot-xaxis-tick"></div>
</div>

Comment: Paste your html

Comment: I find a solution and it works now :
        var $ctx = $( "[id$='item1'] canvas.jqplot-xaxis-tick");
        var ctx = $ctx[0].getContext('2d');